# Maven-cannot release due to local modicfications

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-plugin

We have been releasing our project via Jenkins pipeline. We have a shared pipeline and the mvn release command executes with options
"'-Dgoals=deploy -DpushChanges=false -DlocalCheckout=true -DpreparationGoals=initialize ' +
'-Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dskip.master=true" -DtagNameFormat="@{project.version}" ' +
'-Dresume=false'".

With one of recent project during maven release phase , it fails stating " Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project myProject: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :
14:00:25  [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - [myProject/src/main/java/com/schema/avro/GlobalLinePlanStyle.java:modified].

This file is an autogenerated file for avro schema, which is generated by adding the below plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                    <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.avsc</include>
                    </includes>
                    <testIncludes>
                        <testInclude>**/*.test</testInclude>
                    </testIncludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have tried adding the explicit maven release plugin in pom.xml as below but that also have not solved the issue

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <checkModificationExcludes>
                                <checkModificationExclude>com/schema/avro/GlobalLinePlanStyle.java</checkModificationExclude>
                            </checkModificationExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `release:prepare` expects to find "filters" in `checkModificationExcludes` configuration setting:

> A list of additional **exclude filters** that will be skipped when checking for modifications on the working copy. Is ignored, when checkModificationExcludes is set.

you need to specify either path relative to project root, i.e.:

```xml
<checkModificationExcludes>
    <checkModificationExclude>src/main/java/com/schema/avro/GlobalLinePlanStyle.java</checkModificationExclude>
</checkModificationExcludes>
```

or ant pattern:

```xml
<checkModificationExcludes>
    <checkModificationExclude>**/com/schema/avro/GlobalLinePlanStyle.java</checkModificationExclude>
</checkModificationExcludes>
```

BTW, I do not like such setup, because in my opinion generated source files must not reside in the project structure at all, however other developers [report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66919291/3426309) they experience other difficulties with proper setup of `avro-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Have changed the configuration for auto generated files and that resolved the issue.